# HTML5 contenteditable new line jumps twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

In the example bellow there is some strange behaviour regarding new lines.
For an example in Chrome when you press enter twice the row cursor jumps 3 lines down instead of 2. In Firefox it jumps like this all the time.

```js
jQuery("#message").on("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '\n\n');
    return false;
  }
});

jQuery("#message").on("keyup", function () {
  jQuery("#outcome").html(jQuery(this).html());
});
```

```css
#message, 
#outcome {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="message" contenteditable></div>

<div id="outcome"></div>
```

**EDIT**:
This code seems to work perfectly in all browsers but firefox.

```js
jQuery("#message").on('keydown', function (event) {
  var elem = $(this);
  if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.keyCode === 10) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (JSON.stringify(elem[0].innerHTML).slice(-3).slice(0, 2) === '\\n' || !elem[0].innerHTML.length) {
      return false;
    }

    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '\n\n');
    return false;
  }
});

jQuery("#message").on("keyup", function () {
  jQuery("#outcome").html(jQuery(this).html());
});
```

```css
#message, 
#outcome {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="message" contenteditable></div>

<div id="outcome"></div>
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Just to go in to the next line, without empty line in between.

Comment: I did, I wrote you a comment.

Comment: do you want the `\n` so you save the line breaks in the database? If so, I would process this before it goes into the database, on the server, not in the front end

Comment: No, I am adding additional elements into this div and for keeping code as clean as possible I don't wish to deal with any other elements inside. Lots of logic is already there so I cant just change the behaviour I have to fix it somehow...:)

Answer (score 0):

It probably jumps 3 lines because the enter key injects a new line and after that you inject 2 more new lines.

Try doing this:

```
jQuery("#message").on("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '\n\n');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: That's odd. For me it sometimes only jumps 1 line and most of the time it jumps 2 lines. Never jumps 3 times though. (in chrome) // edit: nvm, now I get what you mean by 3 lines. (1+2 lol)